# how do i perform a list operation for bellow lists

Tags: python, list

```py
lst = ['mango','banana','Watermelon','Papaya']
lst2 = [200,100,500]
```

my lists look like this. I need to access these parameters like first element 1 lst 1 element 2nd list.

I want output like in dictionary.

my code like this I access all elements in that:

`dict = {  "fruit": lst[1], "price": lst2[1] }`

I need a output like this `dict` but I get only one I defined for each element separately I want my output like this but I got only one `dict`

my output `{fruit: mango,price=200}`

expected output:
`[{fruit: mango,prise=200},{ fruit: 'banana',prise: 100}...]`

Comment: Please explain regarding not same length of lists. you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here a one-liner:

```
output = [{"fruit": f, "price": p} for f, p in zip(lst, lst2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response using your code  I get the same output as per my expectation Thank you